# Spark: Lost executor driver on localhost

Tags: apache-spark

I run a Spark application which takes a mysql table (30 million rows), and find patterns.

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

sqlContext
  .read.format("jdbc").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
  .option("url", url)
  .option("dbtable", "MyTable")
  .option("user", "MyUser").option("password", "MyPwd")
  .load().registerTempTable("MyTable")

def getPattern(patent: String) = patent.replaceAll("\\d", "d")

sqlContext.sql("select distinct(code) from MyTable")
  .map(_.getString(0)) 
  .groupBy(getPattern)
  .mapValues(_.size)
  .saveAsTextFile("/tmp/result")
```

I am running the application in localhost. The application fails with:

```
2016-09-30 15:11:47,812 [dispatcher-event-loop-4] WARN  HeartbeatReceiver - Removing executor driver with no recent heartbeats: 129149 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms
2016-09-30 15:11:47,819 [dispatcher-event-loop-4] ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl - Lost executor driver on localhost: Executor heartbeat timed out after 129149 ms
```

Why is this? is it a problem of memory?

Is it a problem with the mysql connection?

I am aware that I could replace `.groupBy(getPattern).mapValues(_.size)` by  `.map(getPattern).countByValue`, making it more efficient and maybe avoid the error. However, this question is about understanding the error.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this (here or somewhere else)? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: no :( .........